# How do I replace last characters with 0?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I have got this so far:

```
mov esi,0                       
mov edi,LENGTHOF source - 2     
mov ecx,SIZEOF source
L1:;iterate a loop
    mov al,source[esi]  
    mov target[edi],al          
    inc esi                 
    dec edi                 
    loop L1
```

From next data

```
source BYTE "This is the source string",0
       BYTE 4 DUP('%')
target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP('#')
       BYTE 4 DUP('^')
```

I got this output:

```
gnirts ecruos eht si sihT#^^^^
```

The target string should not have those characters at the end. I think I need to find the byte that needs to be zero and set it. How do I do that?

Comment: The very first byte you write into `target` is written at offset edi (aka LENGTHOF source - 2).  Then you start writing *backwards*, right?  edi keeps getting decremented as you walk backwards in the string.  So, where do you want to write the zero?  One byte before the first letter, right?  And where was that again?

Comment: The data definitions were crucial for providing the answer. Always beware to not inadvertently invalidate an existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before**

```
This is the source string0
%%%%
##########################
^^^^
```

**After**

```
This is the source string0
%%%0
gnirts ecruos eht si sihT#
^^^^
```

- Because of `mov ecx,SIZEOF source`, the loop has one iteration too many! See how that 4th '%' was overwritten by 0.
- `LENGTHOF source` tallies the characters and the terminating zero. `LENGTHOF source - 1` will point at the offset where you need to write the new terminating zero in the *target*.

This is another version of the loop, one that avoids using the slow `loop` instruction:

```
    mov  ecx, LENGTHOF source - 1  ; destination offset
    xor  ebx, ebx                  ; source offset
    mov  al, 0                     ; terminating zero
L1: mov  target[ecx], al
    dec  ecx
    mov  al, source[ebx]    
    inc  ebx
    test al, al                    ; until we reach terminator
    jnz  L1
```